# linux sort $2 & $17 in numerical values, sort distant columns

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

If we have an input:

```
cpdID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-7788990,1212,2323, IC50 ,,100,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,10,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,8888,9999, IC50 ,,200,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,20,-3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,5555,6666, IC50 ,>,150,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,>,15,-2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

We would love to sort it as : if $2 are the same, they should be in a group.  Within the same $2 group, $17 should be sorted from max to min.

```
cpdID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-7788990,1212,2323, IC50 ,,100,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,10,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,5555,6666, IC50 ,>,150,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,>,15,-2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,8888,9999, IC50 ,,200,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,20,-3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

Numbers of tries and consulting of other posts didn't seem to solve the question.

```
sort -nk2,17 --field-separator=',' input.csv
```

See $2 in cpd-1111: $17 is ordered by "-1.1, -1, -1.2, -1.3".  We would like it to be -1, -1.1, -1.2, -1.3".

```
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,1212,2323, IC50 ,,100,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,10,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,5555,6666, IC50 ,>,150,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,>,15,-2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,8888,9999, IC50 ,,200,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,20,-3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
cpdID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
```

The following two don't do the trick as well.  May we know if any guru might have any comment?  It might be an easy one but stops us for quite a while. Thanks.

```
sort -rnk2,17 --field-separator=',' input.csv

sort -rnk2.17 --field-separator=',' input.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like what you want is

```
sort -r -t"," -k2,2 -k17,17 input.csv
```

Comment: May I know what does "-k2,2 -k17,17" mean?

Comment: This seems to work perfectly.  The shell sort even recognizes float points.

Comment: means "sort according contents of fields 2 to 2, and then according contents of fields 17 to 17". or, simpler,  "sort according contents of fields 2, then 17"

Comment: To go with this, note that your original attempt at using `-k2,17` means to sort using a single key consisting of fields 2 *through* 17, rather than sort on field 2, then sort on field 17.

Comment: I see.  It is a great lesson! Thanks all these gurus!

Comment: Also, if you want to sort on field 2 in ascending order, you can make the `-r` option local to a specific field, rather than specifying it globally. `sort -t, -k2,2 -k17,17r input.csv`.